# Android animation and performClick to create Game AI

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

I am trying to create the illusion of AI through automated clicking of buttons.

I know I can use the animation framework and use performClick on Button views, but can you recommend a way of adding a performClick() call into the animation sequence?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Hi did you ever solve this problem?   I am stuck with something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (MVC inspired approach):

We can create a stack of pre-determined actions:
`Stack<AIAction> replay = new Stack<AIAction>();` (AIAction is the model)

We can then add in each new action to our stack to be replayed later:
`replay.add(new AIAction(AIAction.SELECT,...));`
All the logic and decisions are done here. (controller)

After we have the set of actions, we can replay them and display the animations for the user (view):

```
    for (int i=0;i<replay.size();i++,start+=pause()){
        AIAction thisAction = replay.get(i);

        switch(thisAction.getAction()){

        case AIAction.SELECT:
            scheduleSelect(start,...);
            break;
        case AIAction.REENABLE_CLICKING:
            scheduleReEnableClicking(start);
            break;
        case AIAction.TOAST:
            if (thisAction.getToast())
                scheduleToast(thisAction.getMessage(),start,true);
            else
                scheduleToast(thisAction.getMessage(),start,false);
            break;
        }
    }
```

We now need functions like `scheduleSelect()`, `scheduleReEnableClicking()`, and `scheduleToast()`:
This gives the impression of a "thinking" AI, and allows the user to follow.

```
// for example:
private void scheduleSelect(int start,...){

    Handler handler = null;

handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    // select logic after 'start' milliseconds
    ...
}, start);


}

private void scheduleReEnableClicking(int start){
    Handler handler = null;

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
                     // set clickable logic after 'start' milliseconds
            setClickable(true);
         }
    }, start);
}

private void scheduleToast(final String message,int start){
    Handler handler = null;

    handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        toast(message,pause());
        }
    }, start);
}
```